# Disable length normalization on a single field?

Tags: lucene

I have a field with the following requirements:

1. It must be boosted at index time, therefore 'omitNorms' must remain 'false'
2. However, it must NOT be subject to field length normalization (ie. just because a term is found in 1:10 words vs. 1:1000 should not affect scoring -- both should be equally weighted)

On at least one other field, I DO in fact want field length normalization, and so I do not suspect applying a custom Similarity broadly on the Searcher is appropriate.

How does one boost a single field at index time, but disable the effect of field length normalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PerFieldSimilarityWrapper](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/PerFieldSimilarityWrapper.html) to use a different similarity implementation for each field:

```java
public class MySimilarity extends PerFieldSimilarityWrapper {
    Similarity standardSim = new ClassicSimilarity();
    Similarity nolengthSim = new SimilarityWithoutLengthNorm();

    @Override
    public Similarity get(String fieldName) {
        if (fieldName.equals("someField")) {
            return nolengthSim;
        }
        else {
            return standardSim;
        }
    }

    //These two methods must be implemented here, as their
    //calculation is not field specific
    @Override
    public float queryNorm (float valueForNormalization) {
        return standardSim.queryNorm(valueForNormalization);
    }

    @Override
    public float coord (int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
        return standardSim.coord(overlap, maxOverlap);
    }
}
```

Where `SimilarityWithoutLengthNorm` looks something like:

```java
public class SimilarityWithoutLengthNorm extends ClassicSimilarity{
    @Override
    public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It seems that DefaultSimilarity is deprecated in 5.0. BM52Similarity to become default in 6.0. Is there an equivalent to overriding lengthNorm(...) in BM52Similarity? It does not seem to implement this function.

Comment: @loopforever - It was deprecated more recently, in version 5.5, in fact.  If you want to switch over to BM25, you would need to implement the EncodeNorm and DecodeNorm methods instead.  Keep in mind, this is an entirely different relevance scoring algorithm.

Comment: It appears that in my test case, two documents which are equal in all regards for scoring purposes, with the exception of one field (where the length varies between the two) is still producing a different fieldNorm value: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e9c5194e671a0c7886a . Perhaps I'm doing something wrong? I've simply added searcher.setSimilarity(new CustomSimilarity()) at search time. Am I supposed to be doing something at index time as well? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @loopforever - Yes.  You need to set the Similarity in the [IndexWriterConfig](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html#setSimilarity(org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity)).  Norms are calculated and stored at index time, so the same similarity needs to be set when indexing the documents.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much -- this was all extremely helpful. Hopefully others will find this useful as well. The only change I will suggest to future readers is that 'DefaultSimilarity' be replaced with 'CustomSimilarity' to avoid deprecation warnings in newer versions of Lucene.

Comment: @loopforever - Sure, I've changed it over to ClassicSimilarity.  I'm actually using 5.4 here (haven't got around to updating yet, but then, it's only been a couple weeks), so I was a bit hesitant to post code I couldn't test.